# Sharepoint 2010 - Custom Document ID Provider - Document ID generated - but /_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=ID does not work

Tags: sharepoint

I use a custom document ID provider. The document id gets generated which may be seen when a new file is uploaded to one of the libraries. The Document ID column of the library displays the correct document ID as per the logic in the Document ID Provider. However, if I browse to `/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=<<NEWID>>` I get the following error message

> "OPERATION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY" No documents with ID <> were found in this site collection.

Comment: update: the document id's have started to work right after I posted this question without any changes. Was there may be a timer job involved that ran? I had initially tried stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs but the errors persisted even after that. Can someone help explain to me why it was not working before, and now it works all of a sudden? I believe this to be a timer issue but then why did the stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs command did not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question, it was a timer job issue. There is nothing that can be done about it except change the timer execution delay.